# css float does not show divs in right

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with css float:right; When i remove the `float:right;` in a `.container` then `.app-chat-image-more` will displaying but i need `float:right;`

Here is the **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/EMdbPy)** You can not see the images. When you remove the float:right in `.container` then you can see the images. How can I get along with the display of pictures using float:right; . Anyone can hep me please ?

```css
.container {
  max-width: 60%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #dcf8c6;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  float: right;
}

.app-chat-image-more {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.chat-image-more-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 2 - 2px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% / 2 - 2px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% / 2 - 2px);
  padding: 1px;
}

.app-chat-image-item {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.chat-hidden-image-item {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="app-chat-image-more">
    <div class="chat-image-more-item">
      <div class="app-chat-image-item" style="background-image: url('http://www.cartoondistrict.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/avatar-wallpaper-for-Pc-11.jpg');">
        <img src="http://www.cartoondistrict.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/avatar-wallpaper-for-Pc-11.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @G-Cyr I've entered a different url here so it's not too long.

Comment: Hmm perhaps look at the computed width of the divs in the dev tools?

Comment: @jspcal If you are talking about `calc` i have edited it but same problem.

Comment: Off-topic: None of those vendor prefixes have been needed since IE9 came into fashion (2012 or so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `.container` a `width: 100%`.

Since you've got a `max-width: 60%` set, the width will actually be 60%. But, you need to set a width in order to use `float: right`.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 60%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #dcf8c6;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  float: right;
}

.app-chat-image-more {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.chat-image-more-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%/2 - 2px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100%/2 -2px);
  width: -moz-calc(100%/2 -2px);
  padding: 1px;
}

.app-chat-image-item {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.chat-hidden-image-item {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="app-chat-image-more">
    <div class="chat-image-more-item">
      <div class="app-chat-image-item" style="background-image: url('http://www.cartoondistrict.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/avatar-wallpaper-for-Pc-11.jpg');">
        <img src="http://www.cartoondistrict.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/avatar-wallpaper-for-Pc-11.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```